# How can I set a custom per-person ringtones, but for texts and not calls?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-nexus, ringtone

I know how to set a custom ringtone for a given caller on my phone: pull up the person's entry under People, open the menu and select "Set ringtone." However, this only applies to regular voice phone calls.

Is there a way to do a similar thing for the sound that plays when a "text" — by which I mean either SMS or MMS — is received? If so, what is it? The Messaging app's settings only seem to let me choose a single notification sound, but I'm hoping there's something I'm overlooking.

Comment: Dang, I guess I should have tried more search terms. Thanks, @AlEverett.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's a way to do this using the settings in the built in Messaging app, but there are 3rd party apps that can enhance the built-in app's notifications capability.

I use [SMS Popup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) which lets you carry on using the built-in Messaging app to send and receive text messages, but replaces the notifications. Amongst the extra options it gives you are individual, per-contact customization of every aspect of the notification.

[image: Contact Notifications in SMS Popup]